# lookup in dictionary returns unexpected value

Tags: c#

i have some objects, each object has a point,I created a dictionary for it(I'm not sure if its a best practice),now I want to get the point based on the value,here is what I have done

```
  var x = new Dictionary< EnemisEntity,int>()
   {

       {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="banzai_Bill"},200 },
       {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="beach_koopa" },400 },
       {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="big_boo"},800 },
       {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="blargg"},1600 },

   };
        var m= x.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key.Equals("big_boo")).value;
```

m supposed to return me 800 but it gives me 0,can you please tell me first of all if its a right way I'm doing and second why it gives me zero

Comment: @BradleyUffner may i ask the advantage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
var m = x.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key.enemyType.Equals("big_boo")).Value;
```

In your filter expression `f => f.Key.Equals("big_boo")` `f` is a [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-3.1) with `Key` being of type `EnemisEntity` so comparing it to a string with `object.Equals` gives you false and `FirstOrDefault` returns you default `KeyValuePair<EnemisEntity, int>` which is a [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) with `Value` property initialized to default `int` - `0`.

Without more context (how this dictionary is used) it is hard to argue what design will be more appropriate, other options being - [overriding `Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1#notes-for-inheritors) on `EnemisEntity` or changing dictionary to `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Dictionary`, don't use `FirstOrDefault`. This will do a linear search until it satisfies the `Predicate` negating the benefits of a `Dictionary`'s constant lookup time. You need to use `TryGetValue` on `Dictionary` or one of the equivalent lookup functions.

To use `TryGetValue` and have your entire class act as the key, you will have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to make this work

```cs
public class EnemisEntity
{
    public string enemyType { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is EnemisEntity entity)) return false;

        return ReferenceEquals(this, obj) || string.Equals(enemyType, entity.enemyType);
    }

       
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(enemyType);
    }
}
```

now you can do this

```cs
var x = new Dictionary<EnemisEntity, int>()
        {

            {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="banzai_Bill"},200 },
            {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="beach_koopa" },400 },
            {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="big_boo"},800 },
            {new EnemisEntity{enemyType="blargg"},1600 },

        };

        if (x.TryGetValue(new EnemisEntity { enemyType = "big_boo" }, out var value))
        {
            //do something with your int value
        }
```

However, it seems you're only interested to map the `enemyType` to an `int`, so I would change my `Dictionary` to use `string` as key and not `EnemisEntity` as this makes it all easier

Comment: Creating a new `EnemisEntity` instance every time you need to search the dictionary doesn't seem right. It adds pressure to the garbage collector. I am not downvoting though, because it may be a valid option in some cases.

Comment: I agree, that's why I suggested string as key